# Web Analytics Reports force update

Tags: timer-jobs, central-administration, web-analytics, jobs

What jobs do you need to run to update the metrics for Web Analytics Reports? It looks like they update daily, but I am unsure what jobs to kick off to see it update more regulary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pls. run the jobs in the following order:

“Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Import”

“Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Processing”

“Web Analytics Trigger Workflows Timer Job”

And change the system time to tomorrow or later on the server and run the job as of today.

Answer (score 0):

I would try kicking off the "Web Analytics Trigger Workflows Timer Job" job for the web application in question.  That should include everything you need for the reports to update.

Comment: I've tried it but nothing Happens. I also try to tweak Health Analysis Job, Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Import, Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Processing, Web Analytics Trigger Workflows Timer Job. But nothing happen